# Regular expression matching and replacement R

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I am attempting to write a regular expression that replaces each element in this matrix with only the two numbers after the first colon before and after the comma. There is also "./.:.:.:.:." which I would like to change to "0,0".

```
head(data)    
          Offspring-95_CAATCG         Offspring-96_AAACGG           Offspring-97_ACTCTT          
    [1,] "./.:1,7:8:18:262,0,18"     "0/1:18,4:21:56:56,0,591"     "0/0:27,0:27:78:0,78,723"    
    [2,] "0/0:49,0:49:99:0,147,1891" "0/0:107,0:107:99:0,319,4185" "1/1:0,22:22:66:902,66,0"    
    [3,] "0/0:42,0:42:99:0,126,1324"   "./.:.:.:.:."               "0/1:35,88:117:99:3152,0,718"
```

I have tried:

```
try <- gsub("\\:[0-9]*\\,[0-9]*\\:", \\1, data)
```

The desired output is:

```
    Offspring-95_CAATCG         Offspring-96_AAACGG           Offspring-97_ACTCTT 
[1,]    "1,7"                         "18,4"                         "27,0"    
[2,]    "49,0"                       "107,0"                         "0,22" 
[3,]    "42,0"                        "0,0"                         "35,88"
```

Thanks,

Comment: That looks like a matrix.  What is `class(data)`?

Comment: What is the expected otuput

Comment: Maybe `strsplit`: `strsplit(sapply(strsplit(data, ":"), "[[", 2), ",")`  or just `sapply(strsplit(data, ":"), "[[", 2)`

Comment: WTF? that's not a reproducible example!

Answer (score 2):

This could be done by

```
 sub('[^:]+:([^:]+).*', '\\1', data)
 #   Offspring.95_CAATCG Offspring.96_AAACGG Offspring.97_ACTCTT
 #[1,] "1,7"               "18,4"              "27,0"             
 #[2,] "49,0"              "107,0"             "0,22"             
 #[3,] "9,4"               "33,13"             "13,0"
```

Visualization

```
  [^:]+:([^:]+).*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/YxM-Kp1aosbibJku)

Or using `regmatches` from `base R`

```
  data[] <- regmatches(data, regexpr('(?<=:)[0-9]+,[0-9]+', data, perl=TRUE))
```

Visualization

```
(?<=:)[0-9]+,[0-9]+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/eFEaQGrXib47Hazi)

The above `regex` can be used with `stringr` or `stringi` (for big dataset)

```
library(stringr)
`dim<-`(str_extract(data, perl('(?<=:)[0-9]+,[0-9]+')), dim(data))
 #     [,1]   [,2]    [,3]  
 #[1,] "1,7"  "18,4"  "27,0"
 #[2,] "49,0" "107,0" "0,22"
 #[3,] "9,4"  "33,13" "13,0"
```

Or

```
library(stringi)
`dim<-`(stri_extract(data, regex='(?<=:)[0-9]+,[0-9]+'), dim(data))
 #     [,1]   [,2]    [,3]  
 #[1,] "1,7"  "18,4"  "27,0"
 #[2,] "49,0" "107,0" "0,22"
 #[3,] "9,4"  "33,13" "13,0"
```

#### Update

```
 data1[] <- sub('[^:]+:([^:]+).*', '\\1', data1)
 data1[!grepl(',', data1)] <- '0,0'
 data1
 #   Offspring.95_CAATCG Offspring.96_AAACGG Offspring.97_ACTCTT
 #[1,] "1,7"               "18,4"              "27,0"             
 #[2,] "49,0"              "107,0"             "0,22"             
 #[3,] "42,0"              "0,0"               "35,88"
```

#### data

```
 data <- structure(c("./.:1,7:8:18:262,0,18", "0/0:49,0:49:99:0,147,1891", 
 "0/1:9,4:13:99:129,0,334", "0/1:18,4:21:56:56,0,591",
  "0/0:107,0:107:99:0,319,4185", 
 "0/1:33,13:44:99:317,0,1150", "0/0:27,0:27:78:0,78,723", 
 "1/1:0,22:22:66:902,66,0", "0/0:13,0:13:39:0,39,528"), .Dim = c(3L, 3L), 
 .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Offspring.95_CAATCG", "Offspring.96_AAACGG", 
 "Offspring.97_ACTCTT")))

 data1 <- structure(c("./.:1,7:8:18:262,0,18", "0/0:49,0:49:99:0,147,1891", 
 "0/0:42,0:42:99:0,126,1324", "0/1:18,4:21:56:56,0,591",
    "0/0:107,0:107:99:0,319,4185", 
  "./.:.:.:.:.", "0/0:27,0:27:78:0,78,723", "1/1:0,22:22:66:902,66,0", 
  "0/1:35,88:117:99:3152,0,718"), .Dim = c(3L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(
   NULL, c("Offspring.95_CAATCG", "Offspring.96_AAACGG", "Offspring.97_ACTCTT"
   )))
```

Comment: The base R method worked great. I did get "Warning message:
In data[] <- regmatches(data, regexpr("(?<=:)[0-9,]+(?=:)", data,  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

Comment: @JeffreyMiller Have you tried on the `dput` dataset I posted.  It could be the case that some elements may not have the pattern.  But, then it would be NA.  Can you double check with the data I posted?

Comment: some of the elements are "./.:.:.:.:."  which will represent "0,0"

Comment: @JeffreyMiller  Please provide an example that mimics your dataset

Comment: Updated. Apologies for missing that.

Answer (score 1):

Not regex subbing but probably pretty darn quick.

```
apply(data, 2, function(x) sapply(strsplit(x, ":"), "[[", 2))

##      Offspring.95_CAATCG Offspring.96_AAACGG Offspring.97_ACTCTT
## [1,] "1,7"               "18,4"              "27,0"             
## [2,] "49,0"              "107,0"             "0,22"             
## [3,] "9,4"               "33,13"             "13,0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
out<-list()
for(i in seq(ncol(data)))
    out[[i]]<-gsub('[^:]*:([0-9]+,[0-9]+).*','\\1',data[,i])
out<-as.data.frame(out)
dimnames(out)<-dimnames(data)
out
```